# Проблема с сертификатами при HTTPS запросах

Tags: java, ubuntu, https, certificate

Устанавливал Oracle Java на серверные машины путём переноса папки из `/usr/lib/jvm` с уже настроенных, так как проверенных архивов не сохранилось. Теперь при HTTPS запросах выдаётся ошибка `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`.

Покопавшись, обнаружил, что `cacerts` из `/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-oracle/lib/security` ведёт на несуществующий файл `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts`.

Попробовал:

1. Скопировать данную папку с рабочей серверной машины - ноль эффекта, хотя ссылка указывает правильно.
2. По советам с других вопросов поставил пакет `ca-certificates-java`, который создал папку и сертификаты в `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` - ноль эффекта, возможно из-за того, что `ca-certificates-java` ставит под `openjdk-11`.

Каким образом можно решить проблему?

Comment: Простой поиск по ```Received fatal alert: handshake_failure``` на данном сайте выдал вполне исчерпывающий ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, покопался, обновил вопрос, если знаете ответ - буду рад помощи)

Comment: наверное дурацкий вопрос, но права на папку настроены правильно?

Comment: @ДавидМанжула, перепроверю, но с учётом того, что я самостоятельно папку закидываю, просмотр и редактирование стоит.